# Dynamic ModelViews

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm trying to use Flask-Admin to visualise my database tables.
However, tables can be created and dropped by users at any time, so I would need to achieve one of the following:

1. Modelviews that are instantiated every time a user refreshes the page (based on a table that indexes other tables).
   This did not work for me, with an error indicating that ModelViews could not be added after the app was initialised.
2. A ModelView where the user can select the database table from a dropdown (based on a table that indexes other tables), which changes the ModelView's underlying Model object.
   However, I do not know how to go about doing this.

What is the best way/how to achieve one of these?

Answer (score -1):

I think your second option may have a possible implementation. For example, in Flask-Admin you can make

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin import Admin, BaseView, expose

class MyView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('index.html')

app = Flask(__name__)

admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(MyView(name='Hello 1', endpoint='test1', category='Test'))
admin.add_view(MyView(name='Hello 2', endpoint='test2', category='Test'))
admin.add_view(MyView(name='Hello 3', endpoint='test3', category='Test'))
app.run()
```

which gives you a drop down menu with multiple views. Instad of that you can just instantiate `MyView` as a `ModelView` and iterate over the tables dynamically. i.e

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin import Admin, BaseView, expose

class MyView(ModelView):
    # Disable model creation
    can_create = False

    # Override displayed fields
    column_list = ('field1', 'field2')

    def __init__(self, session, **kwargs):
        # If tables model is the same, otherwise, you need
        # to generate ``TableModel`` dynamically
        super(MyView, self).__init__(TableModel, session, **kwargs)


app = Flask(__name__)

admin = Admin(app)
for index, name, endpoint in get_dynamic_table_datalist(): 
    admin.add_view(MyView(session=db.session, name=name,
                   endpoint=endpoint, category='Tables'))
app.run()
```

Hope this helps. Cheers..

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not allow users to create/delete tables after `app.run()` is executed.
If I move the `admin.add_view()` method to after `app.run()`, flask will raise an Exception, stating that views can not be added after the app is initialised.